# Finding a range in excel for a list of items

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns called Book Name, start page, and end page. For each book it has multiple start and end pages (excerpts of the book) such that my data looks something like:

X 1 3

X 5 6

X 10 15

Y ...

Etc. And it's sorted by smallest to largest. What is the best method of writing a formula that finds the "overall" range for the list of books. So for this example I would want to return on another sheet

X 1 15, since the first page that appears is 1 and the last is 15.

My current solution is count the number of times a book name appears and then write some kind of offset formula based on that but since I'm really new to excel I was wondering if anyone could give me some other approaches (especially since I've heard it's best to avoid offset formulas)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula for the first page if book name is in A2

`=INDEX(start_page,MATCH(A2,Book_Name,0))`

and for last page [edited as per comments]

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(Book_Name=A2),end_page)`

Comment: `And it's sorted by smallest to largest` - didn't notice that - your solution is more efficient:)

Comment: I can't seem to get the last page to work. How does the lookup function work/find the last page?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood how your data is sorted - is Book_Name column sorted? If not then you may need this version `=LOOKUP(2,1/(Book_Name=A2),end-page)` that will find the `last` instance of A2 in `Book_Name` range and give you the corresponding value from `end_page`, which should be the largest if it's the last?

Comment: That works. Thanks! Can you explain what the (1/(Book_name=A2)) is doing?

Comment: =(Book_name=A2) gives you an array of TRUE or FALSE values - when you divide 1 by that array the FALSE values become #DIV/0! errors and the TRUE values become 1s - if you lookup 2 in such an array it matches with the last 1, hence finds the last row where Book_name = A2 and then returns the corresponding value in end_page

Comment: One more question sorry. Why do you match 2 instead of matching 1? Is matching 2 why it's going to the last 1 that's appearing?

Comment: Yes - the "trick" is that 2 won't be found, so in that case the match is with the last number. It's similar to formulas used to find the last number in a range `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A:A)` - 9.99E+307 ("bignum") is [almost] the largest possible value in Excel, so assuming a number that large isn't found it will match with the last number

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for first page:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E3,$B$1:$C$5))
```

and this formula for last page:

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E3,$B$1:$C$5))
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate them.

[image]

**Edit:**

> And it's sorted by smallest to largest

didn't notice it. If your data are sorted - the most efficient way would be solution proposed `@barry houdini`